# integrating swings application in java web project to call swing application on client machine using maven and eclipse

Tags: java, swing, maven, java-ee-7

i have swing java application that has been converted into a jar file which is working standalone .
i need to integrated the application with my web project in order to run this application on client machine .
pls provide me the best solution through which client can call the java swing application in web project through jsp button .

I tried using applets but it gave me the error of class not found.

in this i wrote the applet class in swing project to call its main method in its init method and i had made the jar usein maven and then had put these lines in jsp :

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="com.dell.project.package.JavaSwingToApplet.class" archive="swingcode.jar" width="400" height="400">
  <jsp:fallback>
   <p>Unable to load applet</p>
   </jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>


<applet code="com.dell.project.package.JavaSwingToApplet.class" archive="swingcode.jar" width="600" height="480"> NO </applet>


<applet codebase="/project/src/main/webapp/jsp" archive="swingcode.jar" 
        code="JavaSwingToApplet.class" width="600" height="500">
</applet>
```

Comment: Consider using [tag:java-web-start].

Comment: i tried with that even but was not able to do ... can you pls give me the example with maven and eclipse.